# Returning a list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The first two lines of [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> Beautiful is better than ugly.
>
> Explicit is better than implicit.

I'm writing a function:

```
def get_item_table(self, itemHeader):
    """Returns a specific html table by the 'Item' name."""

    for tbody in self.get_all_tbody():
        for tr in tbody.select('tr td div span'):
            if tr.text.startswith(itemHeader):
                item_table = [parent for parent in tr.parents][3]
                return item_table
```

Is it more Pythonic to write

```
item_table = [parent for parent in tr.parents][3]
return item_table
```

than it is to write

```
return [parent for parent in tr.parents][3]
```

I'm trying to keep the code as simple and as readable as possible. **Clarity**: Which return statement is more Pythonic when returning a list?

Comment: Have you written it like you did because you wanted to document to the reader that the 4th item (index 3) of `tr.parents` is the "item table"?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I did. It doesn't seem like the right thing to do, but it works in the meantime. I want the nearest parent `table`. Feel free to help me improve that.

Comment: OK. I've never used it, but from going over the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) quickly, doesn't `tbody.select('tr td div span')` give you `span`, not `tr`, tags? Are you sure your code does what you want?

Comment: Yes, it does! haha, I've tested it on a number of documents, and up to this point, it works just fine for what I want. It's supposed to check for a `span` with the contents (text) "itemHeader" and get the table it's in. Works. :)

Comment: Wait… your original question title was "Returning a list", but it looks like you are returning the first matching `<tbody>` element, not a list. Could you please clarify what your intentions are?

Comment: Perhaps there has been some miscommunication here… do you by any chance mean "Returning an item from a list" rather than "Returning a list"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question of "which return statement is more Pythonic?"

I believe in this case, it would be best to return it and comment a description:

```
return [parent for parent in tr.parents][3]  # item table
```

(With a more explicit comment).

In this specific case, however, using `[i for i in iter]` is unpythonic. Use:

```
return list(tr.parents)[3]  # item table
```

instead.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it answered my question directly. The other answers we really good, too. Just, this addressed the pythonic/unpythonic question I was asking the best, I think.

Answer (score 5):

#### Style

You mostly use `lowercase_with_underscore` variable and function names, which conforms to the [Python style guide (PEP8)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), but you use `camelCase` for the `itemHeader` argument. Be consistent and change it to `item_header`.

One other minor style issue, at least if you want to conform to the [official docstring conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/):

> The docstring is a phrase ending in a period. It prescribes the function or method's effect as a command ("Do this", "Return that"), not as a description; e.g. don't write "Returns the pathname ...".

#### Naming inaccuracies

- The docstring does not match the function signature. It mentions `Item`, but there is nothing in your code with that name.
- Both the docstring and the function name suggest that a `table` is returned, when it is really a `tbody` (at least if I counted right and understand the [`parents`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parents) function from Beautiful Soup correctly, I may be wrong here).
- The [`select`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) function as you use it iterates over `span`, not `tr` elements. You should therefore also name the loop variable accordingly.

#### Simplification

You inspect the `span` elements for the `itemHeader` and then go up four times (index 3) in the hierarchy, which should lead you to a `tbody` element. But you already have a reference to this element from the iteration over `self.get_all_tbody()`, so there is no need to use `parents` at all.

This also solves your original question, by making it obvious what it is that the function returns.

Here is how the code could look like now:

```
def get_item_table(self, item_header):
    """Return the first table that contains a span whose text
    starts with item_header.
    """
    for tbody in self.get_all_tbody():
        for span in tbody.select('tr td div span'):
            if span.text.startswith(item_header):
                return tbody
                # or, if you want to return the containing `table`:
                # return tbody.parent
```

Since you don't actually want to do something with the individual `span`s except checking if [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) of them starts with `item_header`, you can make the code what I would consider more pythonic:

```
def get_item_table(self, item_header):
    """Return the first table that contains a span whose text
    starts with item_header.
    """
    for tbody in self.get_all_tbody():
        if any(span.text.startswith(item_header)
               for span in tbody.select('tr td div span')):
            return tbody
            # or, if you want to return the containing `table`:
            # return tbody.parent
```

Comment: This answer is really good because it addresses a few style issues in my code and how I could simplify it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a Python guideline for this.
So your two alternatives are neither Pythonic nor non-Pythonic.

In this statement:

> ```
> return [parent for parent in tr.parents][3]
> ```

The expression `[parent for parent in tr.parents][3]` has no name.
The meaning of the expression might not be clear at all to readers.

In this statement:

> ```
> item_table = [parent for parent in tr.parents][3]
> return item_table
> ```

The expression has a name, which makes the code easier to read.
As such, I believe this alternative is better.
You might be able to improve the name further,
for example `nearest_parent_table`.

Note that some IDE's might warn that the variable is redundant.
I don't believe that is a good blanket policy.
When the expression is trivial,
it's better to return directly without a redundant variable.
When the expression is non-trivial,
like in this example,
the variable is not redundant, and I recommend to use it.

Comment: It was between the answer I accepted and this answer. Not sure who downvoted it/why, but I upvoted it.